# simplexml_load_file adding text before '.get_query().'

Tags: php, simplexml

I have trouble adding text keyword "pdf" before `'.get_query().'`

example :

```
$q = simplexml_load_file('http://domain.com/find?q=pdf+'.get_query().'&format=xml');
```

so the result if the get_query keyword is :

macbook pro will be pdf macbook pro , 
sim cool will be pdf sim cool ,
mouse pad will be pdf mouse pad ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `+` give a space after `pdf` so that it becomes

```
$q = simplexml_load_file('http://domain.com/find?q=pdf '.get_query().'&format=xml');
```

Comment: thanks @raidenace it show result, but the result still not pdf

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understand - what result did it show, and what do you mean result still not pdf?

Comment: Space is a reserved character in an URI, IIRC you can not insert it there unencoded safely.